# What Chasam Sofer writes in regards to a Kohen Gadol marrying a Basuleh

Tags: marriage, women, kohen-priest, sexuality, divorce

The [Chasam Sofer in Toras Moshe Parsha Emor](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21620&st=&pgnum=113&hilite=) writes the following:

> A cohen should marry a basuleh (virgin). The Ramabm counts this as a Mitzvas aseh (positive commandment). However one could have the following doubt: If the Cohen Gadol took a basuleh when he was a Cohen hediyot and then became a Cohen Gadol, would he now be required to take another basuleh (get married again)? If so, since (according to the Rambam) a Cohen Gadol is not allowed to have two wives, he would have to divorce the first wife.

Why does the Chasam Sofer have this doubt that the Cohen Gadol should then get married *again*? Meaning *if* the Cohen Gadol would want to get married he needs to marry a basuleh. However in this case that he's already married, why should davka get married again when he becomes the Cohen Gadol?

Comment: Please explain why its not a sofek. You are sure that the answer is -----------?

Comment: He would not have fulfilled the mitzvat aseh of the kohen gadol marrying a betulah if he married her before he was kohen gadol.  Therefore, he'd have to divorce his current wife upon becoming kohen gadol in order to fulfil the mitzvah of the kohen gadol marrying a betulah.

Comment: I appreciate this question (in its clearer form), and I am stunned by the Ch"S here. It seems plain on its face that the Kohen need not get married (and replace the wife to whom he was already married), but then again what do I know? The question, though, becomes, why wouldn't a Kohen Gadol need to celibate to ensure that his wife remains a virgin?

Comment: @SethJ, because it seems like the Rambam is saying that the mitzvah is actually *getting married*-not being married-to a betulah. That would explain why he would have to remarry and why he would not need to remain celibate with his new wife.

Comment: @Daniel, so his question is on the RaMBa"M only? I didn't catch that. (Didn't read the original, only the translation.) Thanks.

Comment: @SethJ, no I think the question is on the Ch"S, although the wording is kind of confusing. I think he's asking how the Chatam Sofer gets from Rambam's point that it's a mitzvat aseh for the k"g to marry a betulah to the point that he must remarry and consequently divorce his current wife.

Comment: @Daniel, I mean the Ch"S's question is on the RaMBa"M's explanation of the Mitzvah.

Comment: @SethJ, yeah I think that's right.

Answer (score 5):

There are some *mitzvos* that one must fulfill only if puts himself in a situation in which the opportunity for the *mitzva* presents itself. For example, there is [a *mitzva* of writing a bill of divorce (*get*) when divorcing one's wife](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40632&pgnum=161). One who does so fulfills a *mitzva*, God's command. However, divorcing one's wife just so as to have the opportunity to do it via a bill of divorce is no *mitzva*.

Other *mitzvos* do not depend on putting oneself in a state of obligation, though they may apply only to certain persons. For example, any father of a firstborn (to his mother) son, no matter what, must do [the *mitzva* of *pidyon haben*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40632&pgnum=97), redeeming the son for five silver *shekel*. The *mitzva* is not "if you redeem your son, do so for five silver *shekel*": it's "you must redeem your son for five silver *shekel*".

I propose that the *Chasam Sofer*'s doubt is whether [marrying a virgin](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40632&pgnum=77) is of the first sort of *mitzva* or of the second sort. If it's of the first sort, then a *kohen gadol* must marry a virgin only if he marries. An already married *kohen gadol* would be exempt. If the *mitzva* is of the second sort, however, then any *kohen gadol* would need to marry a virgin: since (according to the *Rambam* as cited by the *Chasam Sofer*) a *kohen gadol* may not have two wives, he'd need first to divorce his wife.

Comment: re divorcing without basis: the rashba (shut 1:18) iirc says that's a mitzva habaah ba'aveira, but it's still a mitzva.

Comment: @DoubleAA, how is it HaBaah Ba'Aveirah?

Comment: @SethJ Being mean to your wife? Lemme check

Comment: @SethJ msh210 it's 1:18 about halfway through http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1376&pgnum=35 seems he doesn't use the phrase mitzva habaah baaveira though :(

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't mean (or say) that if one divorces his wife just to have the opportunity to do so via a _get_ then the use of a _get_ isn't a _mitzva_. I said that if one divorces his wife just to have the opportunity to do so via a _get_ then the divorcing isn't a _mitzva_.

Comment: @msh210 When is the divorcing a mitzva (in the sense you used the word)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, never. (Well, if there's adultery, maybe. Or some other odd cases. I don't know.)

Comment: Ok. Well, the Rashba says it is a mitzva to divorce _chayvei lavin_ at least (and not just as removal of the issur; he says you would say a bracha on the divorce).

Comment: @DoubleAA, [clever retort](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28094/what-chasam-sofer-writes-in-regards-to-a-kohen-gadol-marrying-a-basuleh/28113?noredirect=1#comment66903_28113). Still, if you divorce your wife "for no reason" you're kind of an idiot, more than being mean. After all, you end up unmarried, and if it was truly for _no_ reason, presumably you still love her and would benefit from remaining married. If you divorce for a _lame_ reason, I'll concede that that's kind of mean, but it would also be cruel to force her to remain married to someone who doesn't love her.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the question is if there is a mitzvah to be married to a besulah or if he can only fulfill the mitzvah when he actually marries a besulah, so if he was married before he will not have the mitzvah only if he gets divorced and marries a besula while he is a cohen godel.